# Jquery Carousel and JQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, jcarousel

Is it possible to use JQuery UI slider with the JQuery Carousel plugin?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

I guess it will be related to callbacks on the `change` event of the Slider plugin, but I have no idea how to tie it in.

My jquery at this stage is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#tiles').jcarousel({
        //auto: 2,
        wrap: 'last'
    });

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        change: function(event, ui) {
        // callback when the slide event fires.         
        }
    });


});
```

Is it even possible? I'd rather figure it out myself but no idea where to start.

I briefly looked for a slider with carousel like functionality but I failed miserably.

Thanks ~

*edit* updated code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#tiles").jcarousel({
        //auto: 2,
        scroll: 1,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        min: 0,
        max:4,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.value);
            jQuery('#tiles').scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(ui.value));             
        }
    });

});
```

presumably I need to know in advance how many items there will be, to set the Slider min/max?

thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read source code of this page - http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html

In your slider you can use:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {            
        carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(ui.value));        
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
   $( ".slider" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
  carousel.scroll(ui.value);
   });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null
  });

  $('.slider1').slider({
    value: 1,
    min:1,
    max:6,              
  }); 

});
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense but I've managed to break it, have posted current code in original post ~. thanks

Comment: yes, I've made a mistake. I'm sorry for that. But I fixed - http://pastebin.com/JZG346SE check this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve something like this? ([link](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/))

There is tutorial with source code, modify your CSS/graphics and you should be just fine ;-)

**Edit:**
Here is more powerfull slider, with rich features :)
([link](http://ajaxdump.com/?9TMQTm8X))

Comment: more or less yes. that looks quite promising, will take a proper look, but looks like I can do what I want using the above (once I stop being thick).

Comment: I have updated my post with additional link, with more advanced slider. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    min:1,
    max:10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        //$('#tiles').scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(ui.value));   
        jQuery('#tiles').jcarousel('scroll',ui.value); 
    }
});
```

works. Not sure if this is the ~best~ way, but it seems to do the trick